# unable to inrement array key

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

The array key is always outputting '1' when i do the array_search no matter the position of value, please how do i correct this?
Foe example array_search of '174' is supposed to output 4 as the key

[image: Array search of 174]
[image: print_r]

```
<?php

$sid = $this->db->get_where('student' , array('class_id' => $class_id))->result_array();

/** Get Mark of Each Student **/

foreach($sid as $rowm){
    $class_pos = $this->crud_model->get_exam_total($row2['exam_id'] , $class_id , $rowm['student_id']);

    foreach($class_pos as $keys => $class_posi){

        $arr = $class_posi['mark_obtained'];
        $arra = array($keys + 1=> $arr);
        $resulte = array_search(174, $arra);

        ?>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $resulte; ?></td>
<?php  }}?>
```

Comment: You can also accept the answer if that sort out the problem, useful for future user

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php

$sid = $this->db->get_where('student' , array('class_id' => $class_id))->result_array();

/** Get Mark of Each Student **/
$arra = array();

$arra[]=-1;// this will start index searching from 1

foreach($sid as $rowm){


$class_pos = $this->crud_model->get_exam_total($row2['exam_id'] , $class_id , $rowm['student_id']);


foreach($class_pos as $keys => $class_posi){

$arr = $class_posi['mark_obtained'];
$arra[] = $arr;
$resulte = array_search(174, $arra);

?>
<td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $resulte; ?></td>
<?php  }}?>
```

Comment: the output is zer0

Comment: @4Jean ah right made an edit, can you echo $arra to make sure you have 174 mark obtained by a student?

Comment: when i echo $arra it dispays the array keyword 'Array' on all the fields

Comment: For array you generally use print_r($arra), and try printing it after both loop so you get one copy

Comment: 0 is the index number of the $arra should contain 174, but I doubt you are using this code, because it must print all the keys from array not only 0, because we arent creating the array more then once.

Comment: Ok it worked, but how do I increment the key to start from 1 and not zero

Comment: i hadto place the $arra = array(); above the loop as you wrote above

Comment: As you know array start with 0th index. But if you really need we can fill 0th with empty data which won't be searched. I will update answer

Comment: ok thanks a lot for your patience. its done but lastly tried to sort the array in descending order but failes with rsort() or sort_desc()